# depth-first in prolog, found the goal but can't keep track of the path

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

This is what I've written so far.

```
goal(g).

arc(a,b).
arc(a,c).
arc(a,d).
arc(c,k).
arc(c,f).
arc(d,g).
arc(d,h).
arc(d,i).
arc(f,l).
arc(h,m).


dfs_start(InititalState,Goal,Solution) :-
                                        dfs([InititalState],[],Goal,Solution).

dfs([H|_],_,Goal,[H]):-
                         Check =.. [Goal,H],
                         call(Check).

dfs([H|T], Explored, Goal, Solution):-
           findall( X, (arc(H,X), \+ member(X,Explored), \+ member(X,[H|T]) ), Children),
           append(Children,T,OpenList),
           dfs(OpenList, [H|Explored], Goal, Solution).
```

I'm using the algorithm as described in the Russel-Norvig. I can't figure out how to create the entire path. I'm missing something here. And the Russel-Norvig, to me, is really cryptic about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in dfs_start/3, you would like to refer to all nodes that were explored in dfs/4, yet dfs/4 has no argument to refer to these nodes. You therefore should introduce an additional argument that you can use for this:

```
dfs_start(InititalState, Goal, Es, Solution) :-
        dfs([InititalState], [], Es, Goal, Solution).

dfs([H|_], Es0, Es, Goal, H) :- call(Goal, H), reverse(Es0, Es).
dfs([H|T], Es0, Es, Goal, Solution):-
        findall(X, (arc(H, X),
                       \+ member(X, Es0),
                       \+ member(X, [H|T]) ), Children),
        append(Children, T, OpenList),
        dfs(OpenList, [H|Es0], Es, Goal, Solution).
```

Example query:

```
?- dfs_start(a, goal, Path, Solution).
Path = [a, b, c, k, f, l, d],
Solution = g ;
false.
```

**EDIT**: From your comment, I now see what you want. This is easy: Just associate to each node in the open list the way it was reached:

```
dfs_start(Start, Goal, Path, Solution) :-
        dfs([Start-[]], [], Goal, Path, Solution).

dfs([H-Path0|_], _, Goal, Path, H) :- call(Goal, H), reverse([H|Path0], Path).
dfs([H-Path0|T], Es, Goal, Path, Solution):-
        findall(X-[H|Path0], (arc(H, X),
                       \+ member(X, Es),
                       \+ member(X-_, [H-_|T]) ), Children),
        append(Children, T, OpenList),
        dfs(OpenList, [H|Es], Goal, Path, Solution).
```

Example query:

```
?- dfs_start(a, goal, Path, Solution).
Path = [a, d, g],
Solution = g ;
false.
```

Consider also that depth-first search is available in Prolog via built-in chronological backtracking, so while it may occasionally be useful to make it explicit (for example, as a starting point for more advanced search strategies), you can do it also with:

```
dfs_start(Start, Goal, Path) :- phrase(dfs(Start, [], Goal), Path).

dfs(Node, _, Goal)   --> [Node], { call(Goal, Node) }.
dfs(Node0, Es, Goal) --> [Node0],
        { arc(Node0, Node1), \+ member(Node1, Es) },
        dfs(Node1, [Node0|Es], Goal).
```

Example query:

```
?- dfs_start(a, goal, Path).
Path = [a, d, g] ;
false.
```

Comment: nope, as you can see the path should be a,d,g and not [a, b, c, k, f, l, d]. Explored is the so called "closed list", not the path to the solution from a.

Comment: Could you please explain the notation X-_ ? Is it like X|_?

Comment: X-\_ is infix notation for the term -(X, \_). I used the functor (-)/2 to build node-path pairs (i.e., nodes and associated paths). To check whether X is already in the open list _including_ H, I do not care about the paths but only about the nodes, so the path can be anything, thus I use a free variable.

Comment: ah sorry, it's the normal minus associated to atoms...didn't get it in there. On the second example, what's -->? It's the first time I see it.

Comment: (-->)/2 is DCG notation; a DCG always describes a list (in this case: the list of nodes in the path); you can read it declaratively by reading (,)/2 as "and then" within DCGs. For example, the path here consists either of Node (if it is a goal), or of Node0 _and then_ the path described by dfs//3 starting from an adjacent node Node1. DCGs are often used when describing lists because they are so convenient for this. They are also used for parsing, where you describe what a list that can be parsed looks like, and then construct something else (like a syntax tree) from it.